# What are the biggest and best SEO and Webmaster Conferences

Tags: discussion

We need to help with marketing this site so it continues to grow.  Check out Robert's post about it [beta site promotion](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/).

I found a site which lists [18 of the best SEO conferences in 2010](http://www.forgeseo.com/18-must-attend-seo-conferences-of-2010).  A couple of them have not occurred yet.  I have listed those below and others that I have found.

What other conferences do people know of besides these for SEO or Webmasters? 
Which ones do you think are the best?  Your votes and comments will help us all so please jump in!

---

- [SMX East](http://searchmarketingexpo.com/east) Oct 4-6th in New York, New York (SEO)
- [SES Chicago](http://www.searchenginestrategies.com/chicago/) Oct 18th - 22nd in Chicago (SEO)
- [PubCon](http://www.pubcon.com/) Nov 8th-11th Las Vegas (Webmaster Conference)

Comment: I thought that finding some in Asia / Australia would be _much easier_ than it has turned out to be. It seems like all the major ones tend to happen in the US.